# Suggestions on making a HUD radar overlay in unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I've been getting a lot of help by reading questions on the forum, but got to a point that what I'm looking for does not appear to be asked, so, here goes my first question.

I'm quite a rookie at coding, and I'm trying to make an small 3D game. Everything's going well so far, but I'm stuck at making a radar overlay.

This is an example of what I'm going for. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AoGYRegc8hI8tC0-GJM2OjXfSg2VBUxj/view?usp=sharing

I want to create an overlay over every enemy with a tag "Enemy". Can get an array with every GameObject with the tag, but have not found a way to create a GameObject over every item on the list and delete it whenever it's not on the list anymore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [OnBecameInvisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) can help you.

```
public class EnemyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...        

    void OnBecameVisible()
    {
         GameObject something = new GameObject("Something");
         something.transform.parent = this.transform;
    }

    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        GameObject something = GameObject.Find("Something");
        Destroy(something);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try it today. Thanks